# What becomes the new default route after connecting to a vpn?

Tags: tcp, routes, udp, vpn, netmask

If you are setting up a new default route for a vpn, does the ip you are connecting to become the default route?

Maybe its the gateway of the ip address at which you are connecting to?

Comment: This is more of a *SuperUser* type of question (https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

After some research, it appears the virtual private tunnel's entire sub-net is the new gateway after connecting to the vpn.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).